# BLE scanner and WiFi web server on the ESP32 board

Tags: esp32

I am trying to put BLE and WiFi web server on the same ESP32 board, using Arduino IDE.
However, BLE library is too heavy. It spends about 73% of program size and there no room for WiFi.

```
Program too big. The size is 1328706 bytes (of a 1310720 byte maximum
```

These are libraries I am trying to use in the same solution:

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEScan.h>
#include <BLEAdvertisedDevice.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
```

Is there anything I can try to spare program size?
Is there any alternative?

Comment: What partition scheme do you use? If you don't use OTA and keep SPIFFS at minimal size, maybe thats enough

Comment: @chrisl, I don't set any partitions. I simply installed ESP32 onto Arduino IDE and merged two examples - `BLE Scan` and `WiFi Web Server`. Honestly speaking, I know nothing about partitions...

Comment: Every board has different tables for dividing the flash memory between the program itself, the SPIFFS for static/persistent files and OTA (over the Air Updates). Please describe, which board ypu have chosen in the IDE and what stettings are selected in the menu for it

Comment: @chrisl, Thanks a lot! I chose another partition and now it works.